# pandas plot ylabels to the right or negative values from right to left

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting a graph with pandas like so

```
df9[(df9['Delivery Quality'] < 0) & (df9['year'] == 2016)][['country','Delivery Quality']].plot(x='country', y='Delivery Quality', kind='barh', figsize=(20,20), legend=False, secondary_y=False)
```

It returns this graph

[image]

This makes it a bit more harder to correlate the name with a column unlike positive values

[image]

The fix would be to either move the ylabels to the right or have the xvalues for the negative values move from right to left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With matplotlib axes' `tick_right()`:

```
ax = frm.plot(x='country', y='Delivery Quality', kind='barh', figsize=(10,5), legend=False, secondary_y='country')
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this which will create a second label on the right side of the plot and hide the label on the left side.

```
ax = df9[(df9['Delivery Quality'] < 0) & (df9['year'] == 2016)][['country','Delivery Quality']].plot(x='country', y='Delivery Quality', kind='barh', figsize=(20,20), legend=False, secondary_y=False)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.set_yticks([])
ax2.set_yticks(df['country'])
```

Comment: this code has a bug from the last line `ax2.set_yticks(df['country'])` the other suggestion though is inherently the same and simpler. It doesn't render the labels so you get 1.0 to 0 as the values for the y axis